# Disable Escape to discard mail with Outlook Web Access

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I often accidentally hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key when preparing emails on OWA, resulting in my draft mail disappearing into the ether. Is there any way to disable this behaviour. I'm using Chrome on Windows 8.